# Application Stop after click on ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

i want to click the list view and update the selected record. But when i clicked the list my apps stop working..

This is my adapter code,

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ViewAllBills.this, ViewBills.class);
        HashMap<String,String> map =(HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String billId = map.get(Config.TAG_ID).toString();
        intent.putExtra(Config.BILL_ID,billId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Is there any wrong with this code?

Actually i still new in android programming and dont really undertstand it..Here is my LogCat after i click the list view and the apps stop working...what does this means?

com.example.Dino.dino E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.Dino.dino, PID: 3280
                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method click(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.LinearLayout
                                                                                       at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:4532)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4496)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

Comment: Could you post the LogCat

Comment: Might I suggest a read?  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Yeah, LogCat would be great

Comment: i already edit my post and add the error LogCat ..

Answer (score 1):

Reading the error message you have a statement android:onclick="click" in your layout file but click(View) is defined nowhere within your Activity/Fragment. You need to provide this method.

Answer (score 1):

`android:onclick="click" remove this line in your xml.`

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity should starting like this to use this method.And remove any onclick you are using in XML file and clean and rerun your app :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}}
```

Firstly add your item into String then add into you hashmap.

```
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String data = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

 HashMap<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(data);
map.put(1, list);
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

**1.** Implement View.OnClickListener in ViewBills like

```
ViewBills implements View.OnClickListener
```

**2.** Override onClick method

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
 //handle click
}
```